# Filtering within groupby function pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by

I'm working in pandas and have a dataframe of sales information with a TradeID, Seller ID,and a Payment date, and I want to calculate for each Seller ID the number of previous succesful Trades, before the current trade date, that the seller has had.  I'm fairly sure that it's a split apply combine style solution but I can't figure out how to achieve it.

The data looks a bit like this

```
|---------|-----------|-------------|------------|
|Trade ID | Seller ID | Payment Date|Success?    |
|---------|-----------|-------------|------------|
|001      |001        |08/12/2016   |Yes         |
|002      |001        |07/12/2016   |Yes         |
|003      |001        |12/12/2016   |No          |
|004      |001        |13/12/2016   |Yes         |
|005      |001        |14/12/2016   |Null        |
|005      |002        |18/01/2012   |Yes         |
|006      |002        |01/01/2011   |Null        |
|007      |003        |07/02/2010   |Yes         |
```

and I'm looking for an output that would be something like:

```
|---------|-----------|-------------|------------|--------------------------|
|Trade ID | Seller ID | Payment Date|Success?    |Previous Succesful Trades |
|---------|-----------|-------------|------------|--------------------------|
|001      |001        |08/12/2016   |Yes         |1                         |
|002      |001        |07/12/2016   |Yes         |0                         |
|003      |001        |12/12/2016   |No          |2                         |
|004      |001        |13/12/2016   |Yes         |2                         |
|005      |001        |14/12/2016   |Null        |3                         |
|005      |002        |18/01/2012   |Yes         |1                         |
|006      |002        |01/01/2011   |Null        |0                         |
|007      |003        |07/02/2010   |Yes         |0                         |
```

I can aggregate the successful trades for each seller, but this does not take in to account the fact that at the point the seller makes the trade they will not have completed all the trades in the dataframe.  For example on 12/12/2016, seller 1 will not have completed the trade on 13/12/2016 therefore their previous successfully completed trades is 2 and not 3.

Any help greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

You can apply filter, then use `groupby` and `count`

```py
df[df['Success'] == 'Yes'].groupby(['Seller ID'])['Success'].count()
```

```
Seller ID
001    1
002    1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[( df['Success?'] == 'Yes' )  , 'Succ'] = 1

df['sumofprevios'] = ( df.groupby('Seller ID')['Succ'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().expanding().sum()))

# you can drop Succ column now.
```

Please let me know if this is not what you need.

Comment: Thanks! i think this looks like it  might work, there's a few NA's in the Success column which are causing the aggregation to fail though, sorry I should have put that in the question.

Comment: I ended up using this solution successfully, but just needed a quick sort of the dataframe by date first.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is to first of all replace the 'Yes' and 'No' with True and False, then groupby the `Seller ID` and sum the `Success?`.

```py
df['Success?'] = df['Success?'].replace({'Yes':True, 'No': False})
df.groupby('Seller ID')['Success?'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

The pandas documentation is quite helpful for figuring these solutions! Below is one possibility that will also allow for recording unsuccessful trades.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{"Trade ID":[1,2,3,4,5,6],
"Seller ID":[1,1,2,2,2,2],
"Payment Date":["2016-12=08","2016-12-12","2012-01-18","2016-02=08","2016-12-16","2012-01-31"],
"Success?":["Yes","No", "Yes", "Yes","No", "Yes"]})
```

Then group on Seller ID

```
grouped_seller = df.groupby("Seller ID")
```

Then you can do multiple different things,  but value counts will count how many times YES or No is for each seller ID

```
grouped_seller["Success?"].value_counts()


Seller ID  Success?
1          No          1
           Yes         1
2          Yes         3
           No          1
Name: Success?, dtype: int64
```

You could then access the seller id using .loc[]

```
grouped_seller["Success?"].value_counts().loc[2]

Success?
Yes    3
No     1
Name: Success?, dtype: int64
```

N.B. the dataframe I create will not have the same dtypes as yours unless you convert dates to datetime